# Manually create a group using SignalR

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I have a list of userDetails connected to a `hub` and I am storing those users to `List<UserDetails>`.I want to add some of the users to a `Group` and broadcast a message to that group.
But I am not able to figure out how can I create a group.This is what I a have done so far:

```
foreach(var user in userDetails)
{
      Groups.Add(user.connectionId, "Connected");
}
Clients.Group("Connected").broadcastMessage(message);
```

Comment: Group is created automatically, when you call `Groups.Add` method. Your example looks ok. What kind of problem do you have with this? Is message not delivered to clients?

Answer (score 11):

when ever you add a user to a group, if that group doesn't exist already it will be created for you, you don't need to create it specifically.